# Delphi TRegEx.IsMatch: How to match an empty string?

Tags: regex, delphi, pcre

How to match for an empty string using Delphi (10.3) [TRegEx.IsMatch](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.IsMatch)?

The following cases return `false` where I would expect to return `true`:

```
fDoesMatch := TRegEx.IsMatch('', '^$');
fDoesMatch := TRegEx.IsMatch('', '^.{0}$');
fDoesMatch := TRegEx.IsMatch('', '\A\z');
```

As I've seen in the docs https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx
Delphi uses C library "PCRE" under the hood to do the regex.

Trying that regex patterns at https://regex101.com/ matches so i wonder why it does not work with Delphi

Comment: I haven't really used RegEx, but according to the documentation you've provided it seems that you are trying to see whether the pattern '^$' exists in the input '', which it doesn't, meaning you should receive false, as you do. Have you tried switching the places of the strings, or have you tried adding an actual string as an input instead of an empty one?

Comment: @Ineffable21 Thank you for your suggestions. As of https://regex101.com/ the pattern `^$` only matches an empty string (tried flavors PCRE and PCRE2). As of docs from  TRegEx.IsMatch, argument order is correct and works with some other different patterns I tried. Using a string variable instead of the literal results in same behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TRegEx` by default does not match empty strings, because it is created with [undocumented](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegExOption) `roNotEmpty` option.

You must explicitly exclude `roNotEmpty` option to enable empty string matches:

```
fDoesMatch := TRegEx.IsMatch('', '^$', []);
```

The decision to use `[roNotEmpty]` as the default was made to maintain backwards compatibility with older Delphi versions. See [A Subtle Delphi TRegEx Change](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2014-october-subtle-regex-change.html).

Comment: Thank you Peter, thats it. I've overseen `roNotEmpty`option. When excluding that option as you described, an emply string could be matched with e.g. `^$`